# Determinant of a special block matrix

Tags: determinant, block-matrices

I have a special $NM \times NM$ matrix of the form

\begin{align*}
S = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 V + \lambda I & V & \cdots & V \\
 V & V + \lambda I & \cdots & V \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
V & V & \cdots & V + \lambda I
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align*}
where $V$ is a symmetric $N\times N$ matrix and $I$ is an identity matrix of size $N$.

I want to know if there is any way to express $\text{det}(S)$ as a function of $\text{det}(V)$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: I just figured out the answer here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460270/determinant-of-block-matrices

Comment: Technically you can’t express even $\det(V+\lambda I)$ as a function of $\det V$ and $\lambda$, since it is literally (up to sign changes) the entire characteristic polynomial of $V$.

Comment: Thanks, @Erick. Yes, I understand. However, for my application, an answer as a function of $\text{det}(V)$ and $\text{det}(V+\lambda I)$ would be quite useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the $M\times M$ block matrix

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 v+\mu & v & v& \cdots & v \\  
 v & v+\mu & v& \cdots & v \\  
\vdots&&&&\\
 v &&  \cdots &v& v+\mu 
\end{pmatrix} = v 11^T + \mu I$$

By the [matrix deteminant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), $$\det(\mu I + v11^T  )=(1+v1^T(\mu I)^{-1}1)\det(\mu I) = \mu^M(1+Mv\mu^{-1}) = \mu^M +vM\mu^{M-1}$$

Now since in your $NM\times NM$ block matrix all blocks commute pairwise, the determinant of $S$ can be obtained by taking the determinant of the above expression after substituting $v$ with $V$ and $\mu$ with $\lambda I$. (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices).

$$ \det(S) = \det((\lambda I)^M + VM (\lambda I)^{M-1}) =\det( \lambda^MI + VM\lambda^{M-1}) = \lambda^{NM}\det(I + \tfrac{M}{\lambda} V) $$

The last expression, afaik, cannot be further simplified. However, asymptotically we have $\det(I+\epsilon V) = I +trace(V)\epsilon$

Comment: Thanks, Hyperplane. According to a previous answer, $\text{det}(S) = \text{det}^{M-1}(V) \text{det}(V+M\lambda I)$. I am trying to see if that matches your answer.

Comment: @Soumitra $V=B$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thank you, @Hyperplane. I was wondering if you can say something about $S^{-1}$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322317/inverse-of-a-special-block-matrix

Comment: @Soumitra $\det(S^{-1}) = \det(S)^{-1}$.

Comment: I hadn't the idea here to use this so versatile matrix determinant formula, maybe because I saw at once the Kronecker structure... Moreover, we arrive at the same formula at the end !

Comment: @Hyerplane, thanks. I was asking if $S^{-1}$ can be expressed in terms of $V^{-1}$ and $(V+ \lambda I)^{-1}$ for which I created another question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322317/inverse-of-a-special-block-matrix

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$R:=\begin{align*}
 \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 V & V & \cdots & V \\
 V & V & \cdots & V \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
V & V & \cdots & V
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align*}=\Omega \otimes V$$

where $\Omega$ is the $M \times M$ matrix with all its entries equal to $1$ and $\otimes$ denotes Kronecker product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Thus, the eigenvalues of $R$ are all possible products between eigenvalues of $\Omega$ (which are $(M,0...0)$) and eigenvalues of $V$ (call them $(\lambda_1,...\lambda_N)$):

$$\text{spectrum}(R)=\left(\underbrace{M\lambda_1,...M \lambda_N,}_{M \times \text{spectrum(V)}} \underbrace{0,0...0}_{(M-1)\times N \ \text{times}}\right).$$

Therefore, as $S:=R+\lambda I_{MN}$ :

$$\text{spectrum}(S)=\left((M\lambda_1+\lambda),... (M \lambda_N+\lambda),\underbrace{\lambda,\lambda,...\lambda}_{(M-1)\times N \ \text{times}}\right).$$

The determinant of a matrix being equal to the product of its eigenvalues :

$$\det(S)=\left(\Pi_{k=1...N}(M\lambda_k+\lambda)\right) \lambda^{(M-1)\times N}$$

Otherwise said :

> $$\det(S)=\det(M V+\lambda I_N) \lambda^{(M-1)\times N}$$

but no direct connection with $\det(V)$.

Comment: Thank you, @Jean Marie. I was wondering if you can say something about $S^{-1}$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3322317/inverse-of-a-special-block-matrix

Comment: I just corrected a misnaming ($S$ instead of $R$) all over my answer without changing the proof.

Comment: The fact that $V$ is symmetric plays no role.