# Inverse of a special block matrix

Tags: inverse, block-matrices

I have a special $NM \times NM$ matrix of the form

\begin{align*}
S = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
 V + \lambda I & V & \cdots & V \\
 V & V + \lambda I & \cdots & V \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
V & V & \cdots & V + \lambda I
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align*}
where $V$ is a symmetric $N\times N$ matrix and $I$ is an identity matrix of size $N$.

I want to know if there is any way to express $S^{-1}$ in a simpler form involving $V^{-1}$ and $(V+\lambda I)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the results from [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3322260/99220) and the idea of [Jean Marie's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3322321/99220): $S = (I_M\otimes\lambda I_N) + ({\bf 1}{\bf 1}^T \otimes V)$

We can rewrite @Accumulation's answer in the stringent form:

\begin{align}
S^{-1} &= \tfrac{1}{\lambda}\big(I_{mn} - (-\tfrac{1}{\lambda}{\bf 1}_m{\bf 1}_m^T \otimes V)\big)^{-1}
\\&=\tfrac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-\tfrac{1}{\lambda}{\bf 1}_m{\bf 1}_m^T \otimes V)^k \\
&=\tfrac{1}{\lambda}(I_m\otimes I_n) + \tfrac{1}{m\lambda}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-\tfrac{m}{\lambda})^k ({\bf 1}_m{\bf 1}_m^T \otimes V^k) \\
&=\tfrac{1}{\lambda}(I_m\otimes I_n) + \tfrac{1}{\lambda}\big(\tfrac{1}{m}{\bf 1}_m{\bf 1}_m^T \otimes \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-\tfrac{m}{\lambda}V)^k\big) \\
&=\tfrac{1}{\lambda}(I_m\otimes I_n) +\tfrac{1}{\lambda}\big(\tfrac{1}{m}{\bf 1}_m{\bf 1}_m^T \otimes (I_n+\tfrac{m}{\lambda}V)^{-1}-I_n\big)\\
&= \tfrac{1}{\lambda}\Big((C_m\otimes I_n)+
\big(\tfrac{1}{m}{\bf 1}_m{\bf 1}_m^T \otimes (I_n+\tfrac{m}{\lambda}V)^{-1}\big)\Big)\end{align}

Note that the matrix $C_m = I_m - \tfrac{1}{m}{\bf 1}_m {\bf 1}_m^T $ is known as the [(geometric) centering matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centering_matrix)

Here the Neumann series converge if $\| \tfrac{1}{\lambda}{\bf 1}_M{\bf 1}_M^T \otimes V\|<1 $ and $\|\tfrac{M}{\lambda} V  \|<1$. If we take the Frobenius norm, both are equivalent to $\|V\|_{F}<\tfrac{|\lambda|}{M}$

**EDIT:** fixed mistake with handling $k=0$ term

Comment: Thank you, @Hyperplane. Just one worry. $S^{-1}$ just derived has two exactly same rows. Does that not make $S^{-1}$ non-invertible?

Comment: @Soumitra good eye, there was an issue with the $k=0$ term, I fixed it

Comment: Thank you, @Hyperplane

Comment: Hi @Hyperplane, For my application, I can show that $|V_{ij}|<1$. So the only obstacle for meeting the condition for Neumann series is the factor $\lambda$. Is there a way to handle that? I mean considering the new norm $\|A\|_* = \frac{1}{\lambda}\|A\|_F$.

Comment: For my application, we can assume $\lambda > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following analysis might work:

Expressing $S$ as $\lambda(I_{nm \times nm}-\frac {-1} {\lambda} W)$ where $W$ is your matrix, except without the $\lambda I$ (that is, $W$ is a block matrix where each block is $V$), $S^{-1}$ is equal to the geometric series $\frac 1 {\lambda} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{\lambda}W)^k$.

$W^k$ is a block matrix where each block is $m^{k-1}V^k$ (I prefer lowercase variable names for integers, to distinguish them from matrices). So then each block of the inverse is $\frac 1 {\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{\lambda})^km^{k-1}V^k=\frac 1 {m\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{\lambda})^km^kV^k=\frac 1 {m\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-m}{\lambda}V)^k$, which is yet another geometric series, and it converges to $\frac 1 {m\lambda}(I+\frac{m}{\lambda}V)^{-1}=(m\lambda+m^2V)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, @Acccumulation. One basic thing I am not able to understand is that both $W$ and the resulting block matrix, say $T$, are singular matrices. Then $T$ not invertible and hence $T^{-1}$ is not equal to $S$. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: @Soumitra It's $W+\lambda I_{nm \times nm}$ that's inverted, not $W$. Is that where your confusion lies?

Comment: My confusion is about the resulting matrix, say $T$, whose each block is $(m\lambda I + m^2 V)^{-1}$.

Comment: I guess you are using Neuman series. However, that has some assumption on $W$. Right? I am not sure if that assumption is satisfied here.